# c++: Reference array of maps

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a function which creates an array of Maps:

```
map<string, int> *pMap
```

And a function which writes maps to the array:

```
int iAddMap(map<string, int> mapToAdd, map<string, int> *m, int i)
{
    m = &(pMap[i]);
    memcpy(m, mapToAdd, sizeof(map<string, int>));
}
```

And a function to get maps from the array

```
map<string, int>& getMap(int i)
{
    return pMap[i];
}
```

I can write maps to the array without any issue, but every get call results in a seg fault:

```
int val; 
// val defined after this
map<string, int> * pGetMap = &(getMap(val));
```

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: why not use a vector of maps?

Comment: "Any suggestions on why this is happening?" Yep. You urgently need to pick up a basic C++ book and read that thoroughly. There's no much wrong with your code, I wouldn't know where to start. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use memcpy() to copy objects like maps, or indeed any other kind of C++ container - you need to use assignment, which takes into account the map's underlying structure and se,mantics. And you should be using a `vector <map>`, as you actually seem to want a copy rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Never ever use `memcpy` for copying an object of a map (or whatever class, for that matter) - use assignment or copy constructor instead. `memcpy` is a C function, which has no idea of the internal structure of a C++ object, so it is almost guaranteed to mess things up.

Also you would better use an `std::vector<map<string, int> >` instead of an array:

```
std::vector<map<string, int> > maps;

void addMap(const map<string, int>& mapToAdd, int i)
{
    maps[i] = mapToAdd;
}

map<string, int>& getMap(int i)
{
    return maps[i];
}
```

Note: `addMap` does not return anything in your example code, so I changed its return type to `void`. Also I pass `mapToAdd` as const reference rather than by value.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an unholy mix of C and C++ programming, begin with changing:

```
memcpy(m, mapToAdd, sizeof(map<string, int>));
```

to

```
*m = *mapToAdd;
```

Also in the function

```
int iAddMap(map<string, int> mapToAdd, map<string, int> *m, int i)
```

What is the purpose of `m`? Any modifications to `m` won't be seen outside of this function.

Comment: You probably meant *m = *mapToAdd;

Comment: this will set the vector to the same address. and you probably meant &mapToAdd (address-of operator and not dereference operator)

Comment: @knittl What vector? Both `m` and `mapToAdd` are pointers to `std::map` so doing `*m = *mapToAdd` will assign the map `mapToAdd` is pointing at to the map `m` is pointing at.